# I can't render tmx file in cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-js, tiled, tmx

When I loaded .tmx file in cocos2d-JS which was created by Tiled and tried rendering in view,
I could not render and the following error were output
[image]

and the contents of .tmx file is

[image]

I want to render as follows

[image]

why I can't render?

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-JS has a [limited support for TMX format](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/TileMap#Tiles).

> - Embedded tiles are NOT supported (i.e., tilesets with embedded
>     images).
> - Only embedded tilesets are supported (i.e., the tileset is embedded,
>     but not its images).
> - supports at most 1 tileset per layer.

So to fix your problem:

1. While saving to TMX - save metadata only (images will be served from external files). Currently i see "encoding=base64 compression=zlib" line in your file - Cocos2d-JS won't render that one.
2. One tile per layer means exactly one tile per layer. If you want to draw a nice map using multiple tiles per layer - Cocos2d-JS won't render it correctly (It will be a horrible mess of wrong tiles basically). What I suggest you to do instead is to draw your map in Tiled and to *export it as an image*. Then you  create another TMX file with your beautiful level as **background image** and use some basic red/green/blue rectangles (one per layer) to place enemies, bonuses e.t.c. so you'll be able to read the meta of those tiles from cocos2d-JS (you can keep this meta TMX layer invisible and just draw it on top of basic image layer with your map)
   [image]